# нарисовать результат canny поверх изображения

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

возможно ли отобразить получившиеся линии после эффекта Канни, поверх исходного изображения?

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так (Python):

```
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny=cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 50)
canny=cv2.cvtColor(canny,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out_image=cv2.bitwise_or(canny, image)
cv2.imwrite('out_image.jpg',out_image)
```

Comment: можно еще bitwise_xor использовать